# Error Cannot reinitialise DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

Tengo una tabla donde la cargo con DataTables y quiero personalizar el idioma, pero me da error de la manera en como lo estoy haciendo.

Error:

> DataTables warning: table id=table - Cannot reinitialise DataTable.

Aca el código:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#table').DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": "tabla/cargos",
                "columns": [
                    {
                        sortable: false,
                        "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
                            var cant=1;
                            cant++;
                            return meta.row+1;
                        }
                    },
                    {data: 'nombre'},
                    {
                        sortable: false,
                        "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
                            return '<button class="edit-modal btn btn-info" data-id="'+full.id+'" data-nombre="'+full.nombre+'">'+
                                    '<span class="fa fa-edit"></span> Editar'+
                                   '</button> '+
                                   '<button class="delete-modal btn btn-danger" data-id="'+full.id+'" data-nombre="'+full.nombre+'">'+
                                    '<span class="fa fa-trash"></span> Eliminar'+
                                   '</button>'
                            ;
                        }
                    },
                ]
            });
            $('#table').dataTable( {
                "language": {
                    "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
                    "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                    "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
                    "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
                    "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                    "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                    "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                    "sInfoPostFix":    "",
                    "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
                    "sUrl":            "",
                    "sInfoThousands":  ",",
                    "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                    "oPaginate": {
                        "sFirst":    "Primero",
                        "sLast":     "Último",
                        "sNext":     "Siguiente",
                        "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                    },
                    "oAria": {
                        "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                        "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
                    }
                }
            } );
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estas tratando de inicializar la misma tabla dos veces, y eso es algo que no permite el plugin, puedes obtener mas informacion en el siguiente link

https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3

Para evitar ese error, coloca

```
   "language": {
                "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
                "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
                "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
                "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                "sInfoPostFix":    "",
                "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
                "sUrl":            "",
                "sInfoThousands":  ",",
                "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sFirst":    "Primero",
                    "sLast":     "Último",
                    "sNext":     "Siguiente",
                    "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                },
                "oAria": {
                    "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                    "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
                }
            }
        } );
```

dentro de tu primera llamada a  `$('#table').DataTable()`.

Comment: Gracias bro. Para el que tenga dudas o problemas para agregar el lenguaje, antes de "language" va una coma :D

Comment: ¿alguna manera de colocarlo en un archivo externo? donde simplemente se haga el llamado, es para no estar repitiendo eso cada vez que se ejecute esa función.

Comment: claro, crea un archivo js externo, y colocalo entre la funcion $(document).ready(function(){}); luego llámalo después de que hayas creado tu tabla antes de cerrar la etiqueta <body>

Comment: gracias hermano :D